# RSS Feed to contain posts from 1 category only

Tags: rss

I am using a theme with many custom post types but I would like my main RSS feed `www.domain.com/feed` to show posts and custom post types from one category only.

The categoy is defined within `Posts / Categories`.

1. How can I do this?
2. Is this bad for SEO?

In any case, I have noticed that my posts take a few days to be indexed by Google even if they are included in the RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you if you put it in the functions.php file in your theme. Just replace where I have "CATEGORY NAME HERE" with the category name.

```
function custom_feed_wpse_128087($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed'])) {
        $qv['post_type'] = get_post_types();
        $qv['category_name'] = 'CATEGORY NAME HERE';
    }
    return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'custom_feed_wpse_128087');
```

Comment: I have added this but nothing seems to happen .. I have also tried 'category_id'...

Comment: Remove `$qv['category_name'] = 'CATEGORY NAME HERE';` to make sure your custom post types are showing in the main feed. If they do, are you using `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'POST TYPE HERE');` when you created your custom post types?

Comment: The custom post types are indeed showing and i am not using this statement you are mentioning

Comment: @JoannaMikalai by default custom post types are not using the default categories or tags. That other statement is needed when you create your custom post types. Also in the [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function you will need `'taxonomies' => array('category')`. Hopefully this helps you out more.